# Is Firefox 6.0 a security and stability update?

Tags: security, firefox

I'm on Firefox 5.0 and just got a popup, translated from Swedish:

> A security and stability update for Firefox has been downloaded and is ready to be installed.
>
> Update: **Firefox 6.0**

Is Firefox 6.0 -- a major version higher than 5.0 -- really a security and stability update? I'd rather not update since I'm happy with 5.0 (I thought I was on 3.0 before I checked), but if it's a security update, it doesn't leave me much of a choice.

Comment: Do them just want more cakes?

Comment: **Please just update.** Firefox has changed its release cycle, they are going to bump major versions like crazy and you want to always have the latest version.

Comment: @slhck: So I'll just assume there's a "1." in front of every version number?

Comment: @Tim That's one way to deal with it. Actually, they were even thinking of [dropping version numbers altogether](http://www.tomshardware.com/news/firefox-version-number-mozilla-web-browser,13231.html).

Comment: @slhck Perhaps soon they will just have 'best before' dates like a block of cheese.

Comment: @Tim It's more of a change in release attitude. Think of it as "Version doesn't matter. The user should always use the latest version and things should not break between consecutive updates.". Both release schemes have pro's and con's, it's just more unusual. Chrome however does it succesfully (but that doesn't require admin rights to update)

Comment: Oh, I like the "best before date idea Linker.

Answer (score 5):

Firefox is emulating Chrome in order to not be perceived as being as behind due to a comparison (unfair, I think) between their relative release cycles.

FF6 is still a "major" update. They've just streamlined their update cycle so that each major update is probably less major than before.

Unless the new version really has problems, I'd go to it.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://www.eweek.com/c/a/Desktops-and-Notebooks/Mozillas-Firefox-6-Performance-Tweaks-but-No-Huge-Changes-567905/) is an article that has more info, but its basically just a lot of tweaks.

There are some security fixes (see [here](http://www.mozilla.org/security/announce/2011/mfsa2011-29.html)).